# Spring boot + OCPSoft urlRewriter + angular ui router html5mode

Tags: java, angularjs, angular-ui-router, spring-boot

I'm trying to integrate Spring boot with OCPSoft urlRewriter and using angular ui-router in html5mode, my configuration is this:

The main of Spring boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableWebMvc
public class CustomerTrackerApplication implements ServletContextInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomerTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(RewriteServletRequestListener.class);
        servletContext.addListener(RewriteServletContextListener.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps = EnumSet.of(
                DispatcherType.REQUEST,
                DispatcherType.FORWARD,
                DispatcherType.INCLUDE,
                DispatcherType.ERROR
        );

        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();

        registrationBean.setFilter(new RewriteFilter());
        registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(disps);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");

        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```

the url rewriter:

```
@Component
public class UrlRewriteFilterConfiguration extends HttpConfigurationProvider {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager
            .getLogger(UrlRewriteFilterConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(ServletContext context) {
        return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()

                .addRule()
                   .when(Direction.isInbound().and(Path.matches("{path}")))
                   .perform(Log.message(Level.INFO, "Client requested path: {path}").and(Forward.to("/index")))

                   .where("path").matches("\\/app/.*");
    }

    @Override
    public int priority() {
        return 10;
    }

}
```

the angular code:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider,$locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
            $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                    url: '/app',
                    abstract: true,
                    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
                })
            .state('app.customersTracking',{
                url:'/customersTracking',
                templateUrl: CONSTANTS.APP_VIEW_TEMPLATES_PATH + 'customerServiceTrackings.html',
                controller: 'customerServiceTrackingController'
            });
        });
```

The problem ocurs when i go to http://localhost:8080/app/customersTracking the page redirects to index but the chrome console raise these errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/app/libs/Bootflat/css/bootflat.min.css".
customersTracking:11 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/app/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css".
customersTracking:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/app/libs/requirejs/js/require.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
customersTracking:10 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/app/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css".
customersTracking:13 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/app/libs/requirejs/js/require.js".
```

i think is because i'm using thymeleaf of spring boot, but i don't know if is this the problem, what i can do for correct it?